# If I have a function inside a module, which returns a custom structure, can I make that structure inaccessible outside of the module?

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about scope here.

Say I have the following module:

```
Public Module SampleModule

    Public Function SampleFunction() As SampleStructure
        Return New SampleStructure(123, 456)
    End Function

    Structure SampleStructure 'Do not want this accessible elsewhere in project
        Public A As Integer
        Public B As Integer
        Sub New(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
            Me.A = A
            Me.B = B
        End Sub
    End Structure

End Module
```

The function `SampleFuncton()` is the only code in the entire project that will ever need to create a new instance of `SampleStructure`.  I want the function accessible anywhere in my project, but I do not want the structure accessible anywhere, and I don't want it to show up in Intellisense anywhere else.

Is this even possible?

Comment: change one word and add two others and you have a proper class with which you can do most anything

Answer (score 3):

If what you really want to do is just prevent other assemblies from creating instances of `SampleStructure` you are looking for the access modifier [`Friend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx)

Change the constructor of `SampleStructure` to the following

```
Friend Sub New(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
    Me.A = A
    Me.B = B
End Sub
```

If you truly want to make the structure accessible only inside your assembly but still have the function accessible to the outside world, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. You are returning an instance of the struct so other parts of your program will need to have visibility. How would they be able to interact with it otherwise, or know what type the function returns?

If you were not returning an instance, you could make it private.

Comment: Well, the idea was to have it be read-only in a sense.  So you can read from the structure but not instantiate it.  So you could write.. `Dim TestValue as Integer = SampleFunction().A`

I know, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  I've run across the need for something similar in the past and I just thought to ask about it.

Comment: In that case you could make the constructor friend. But that would only make it hidden outside of the current assembly

Comment: Ok thank you.  I didn't think it was possible, but figured I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an alternative approach. All the following code should be placed inside your module.

**1)** Create an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx) which exposes all the properties, methods, function etc. you would like to be accessible.

```
Public Interface Sample
    ReadOnly Property A() As Integer
    ReadOnly Property B() As Integer
End Interface
```

**2)** Create a private structure and implement the `Sample` interface.

```
Private Structure InternalSample
    Implements Sample
    Friend Sub New(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
        Me.m_a = A
        Me.m_b = B
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property A() As Integer Implements Sample.A
        Get
            Return Me.m_a
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property B() As Integer Implements Sample.B
        Get
            Return Me.m_a
        End Get
    End Property
    Friend m_a As Integer
    Friend m_b As Integer
End Structure
```

**3)** In the `GetSample` function, create a new instance of `InternalSample`, set desired values and return the object.

```
Public Function GetSample() As Sample
    Dim struct As New InternalSample(123, 456)
    'You can still change the values before returning the object:
    struct.m_a = 321
    struct.m_b = 654
    Return struct
End Function
```